# how to select content in database?

Tags: sql-server

I would like ask if this is possible in any database. Lets say there's one column on my database that has a content like this:

```
 -----------------
|columname       |
 -----------------
| roan,joan,keith|
------------------
```

If I do a select query, can I just display roan from that field?

Thanks,

Comment: What database are you using?  The question should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm using MSSQL for my DataBase.

Comment: Will you always want to only select `roan`? Will you want to select everything before the first comma? What if your data is `,roan,joan,keith`?

Comment: @AdamWenger the selection will be based on the user who is logging in the system. and also the "," will be remove I've just stated in there for example purposes only.

Comment: Can I now delete this question? Because I have found an answer to it and from that answer I want to post another new question. Or do I still need to rephrase my question and at the same time post my new question here also?

Comment: @user3317319 If you have a new question, you can post that separately.  Try to provide as much information as you have so you can get good assistance from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL version of Mark answer:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(columnname, 1, CHARINDEX(',', columnname, 1) - 1) FROM testtable;
```

Comment: #thepirat000 thanks for this sample query I'll try this later when I get back to my desk.

Comment: can I also include a where clause in that sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle solution:

```
select substr(columnname,1,instr(columnname,',')-1) from testtable;
```

Comment: @markjbobak thanks for the sample query